# Asp.net Dropdownlist onchange not firing after value is assigned to dropdownlist using a datatable

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have the following drop down list on jobs.aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrentJobTitle" runat="server" class="ComboStyle" ClientIDMode="Static" size="1" ONCHANGE="ShowHideFields()">
```

The ddlCurrentJobTitle is filled with data from database in Page_Init

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        ///fill ddlCurrentJobTitle dropdownlist with JobTitles
        ///

        SharedClass.BindJobTitles(ddlCurrentJobTitle);
}
```

After that, the user selects employee and according to the employee_id, the ddlCurrentJobTitle is assigned values using Datatable

```
public static void DisplayJobTitleByEmployee(DropDownList ddlCurrentJobTitle, int empID)

    {
        using (DataTable dt = dbObj.GetJobTitleByEmployee(empID))
        {
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    ddlCurrentJobTitle.SelectedItem.Text = dt.Rows[0]["JobTitle"].ToString();
                    ddlCurrentJobTitle.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["JobCodeID"].ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is:

After the page is loaded first time, and the `ddlCurrentJobTitle` is filled with jobs, if I select jobs manually, the `ShowHideFields()` is called, and table rows are shown and hidden according to jobtitle

However, when I select employee and when `ddlCurrentJobTitle` is assigned values using datatable programatically, the table rows are NOT shown and hidden according to jobtitle

perhaps the `ShowHideFields()` not fired

I want the `ShowHideFields()` called according to the datatable text/value assignment

Please note that I do not want to use `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: if you dont want to post it back on change, how do you expect a serverside function to fire? the server is not telepathic...

Comment: I apologize, but I want the javascript function ONCHANGE="ShowHideFields()" to be fired at client side. Thanks.

Comment: Oh in that case the answer is simple, "onchange" in asp is asp's event. If you want the client side function to fire on change, on aspx page it would be "OnClientChange" or something of this sort if i remember correctly